# Laying a text over another text in response to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

So I am trying to figure this out and I'm quite lost. This is what I would like my program to do.

```
TEXT1

button
```

When I press the button, I would like this to happen:

```
TEXT2

button
```

When I press the button again, I would like:

```
TEXT3

button
```

And for the last text, I would like the button to disappear:

```
TEXT4
```

So I'm not really giving the user an option to go back and read the previous texts if she already clicked the button to read the next text.

Now, this is the closest to my getting to producing this effect. I would assign a class to all my  `TEXT`s. Let's call it `Texts`. And I will give my button a class. Let's call it `readMore`. And to `readMore` I will call, `click(function({}))`. So when I click the button, I would call `fadeOut()` to `(this)`, which is the current text, `TEXT1`. And then call `fadeIn()` to `(next)`, which is `TEXT2`. But then problem with this is that `(This)` will always refer to `TEXT1` and `(next)` will always refer to `TEXT2`. So that is my problem. Any possible solutions?

This is my code that I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.readMore').click(function(){
        $('.texts').(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).next().fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute for texts blocks, but you need fixed height container for it. Also you can make a text container for showing, and hide all texts in blocks with `display: none;` and replace html from it to visible container

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems correct. You have a click event on the button and every time you click it you change the text. You can change the text by changing the `innerHTML` of the `$('.texts')` element.
Also in order to have the different text numbers 1, 2, 3 etc you can add a global variable `var globalCounter = 0;` and increase the `globalCounter` by 1.

So something like the code below should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var globalCounter = 0;
    $('.readMore').click(function(){
        globalCounter++;
        $('.texts')[0].innerHTML = "Text "+ globalCounter; 
    });
});
```

Also if you want the button to disappear when Text 4 is shown you can add a simple if statement which checks the globalCounter variable. When it is 4 you can set the button's `display` property to `none`

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my question much more. Text 1 is supposed to represent a paragraph. And Text 2 is much different than Text 1 than just the number. The entire content will be different. Sorry! I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
var MAX_CLICK_COUNT = 4;
var currentCount = 1;
function updateLabel(){
    $("h3").html("TEXT "+ ++currentCount);
    if(currentCount == MAX_CLICK_COUNT) $("button").hide();
}
```

And, [**here's the fiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwmgeyrp/)

---

**Update:**

```
var MAX_CLICK_COUNT = 4;
var currentCount = 0;
var content = ["Paragraph text 1", "Paragraph text 2", "Paragraph text 3", "paragraph text 4"];
function updateLabel(){
    $("h3").html(content[currentCount++]);
    if(currentCount == MAX_CLICK_COUNT) $("button").hide();
}
```

And here's [**the updated fiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwmgeyrp/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my question much more. Text 1 is supposed to represent a paragraph. And Text 2 is much different than Text 1 than just the number. The entire content will be different. Sorry! I should have been more clear.